# Reading file from path : AWS EC2 container service

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am trying to read content of different file into docker container. Files are present on the EC2 host and I want to read contents of file as part of task definition file environment parameter.

```
environment": [
        {
          "name": "ENVIRONMENT",
          "value": "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
        }
      ]
```

This key value json is in a file and I want to read it as environment variable, (not like currently I am reading it as stringified json).

How can I do this?

Comment: For clarification, are you trying to inject interpolated values into the container(s)? For example, the output of a cloud formation template command? Like a resource name for example?

Comment: No. I am trying to load a json input file based on an environment variable using ECS.